# Problems creating/accessing objects in a class array

Tags: arrays, object, methods

I'm trying to use a class to hold information about objects my code will be creating, but I'm having problems storing the information in an array and then accessing a method in the class. Right now when I try to add an object, it's throwing a null pointer exception.

The Class:

```
public class MPObjects {
    private Object type;
    private String name;

    public void setObject (Object object) {
        type = object;
    }

    public Object getObject() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setName(String objName) {
        name = objName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

The array declaration in another class:

```
public MPObjects[] mpObject = new MPObjects[500];
```

Trying to add a new object:

```
public void addPlotControl(Object thisObject, String controlName ) {
        mpObject[0].setObject(thisObject);
        mpObject[0].setName(controlName);
        }
```

And then, which I can't get to work as well, I'm trying to run a method in the object. I know it's something like this, but not sure how to type cast and access a method properly:

```
(ClassType)(muObject[0].getObject()).someMethod();
```

I also tried a List, but couldn't figure out how to add/access the data fields in it.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone, not sure about the first part, but I'm holding the objects in:

```
    public static List<Object> myControls = new ArrayList<>();
```

And I can access the object methods using:

```
    ((ButtonControl) myControls.get(0)).startThread();
```

Wasn't placing ()'s in right places...